# BitConverter.ToInt16() produces unexpected result

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have the following code about a checkers game function that handles moves:

```
public void convertMoveToIntValues(KeyValuePair<string, string> move, ref Int16 fromNumInt, ref Int16 toNumInt) {
    Byte[] fromNumTemp = { 0, 0 };
    Byte[] fromNum = {0,0,0,0};
    fromNumTemp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(move.Key);
    fromNumTemp[0] -= 96;
    fromNumTemp[1] -= 48;
    fromNum[1] = fromNumTemp[0];
    fromNum[3] = fromNumTemp[1];
    fromNumInt = (Int16)(BitConverter.ToInt16(fromNum, 0) * 8 + BitConverter.ToInt16(fromNum, 2)); 
    Byte[] toNumTemp = {0,0};
    Byte[] toNum = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    toNumTemp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(move.Value);
    toNumTemp[0] -= 96;
    toNumTemp[1] -= 48;
    toNum[1] = toNumTemp[0];
    toNum[3] = toNumTemp[1];
    toNumInt = (Int16)(BitConverter.ToInt16(toNum, 0) * 8 + BitConverter.ToInt16(toNum, 2));
}

public void Main() {
    Int16 a, b;
    convertMoveToInt(New KeyValuePair<string, string>("c3","b4"), a, b);

   Console.Writeline("The puppet moves from place no. " + a + " to place no. " + b);
}
```

I get the wrong solutions like: a=6912 and b=5120.

I use two kinds of Byte[], the first for an ASCII to Byte conversion, and then the other for the Byte to Int16 conversion.
A good reference for the topic is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16(v=vs.110).aspx

All things goes well until the last row, where it produces an incorrect result.

Could you help me getting the right answer?

Comment: Did you expect (27, 20) instead of (6912, 5120)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want:

```
toNum[0] = toNumTemp[0];
toNum[2] = toNumTemp[1];
```

instead of:

```
toNum[1] = toNumTemp[0];
toNum[3] = toNumTemp[1];
```

(I also suggest you write a method that receives a `string` and returns a `Int16` to save you writing the same code twice)

Answer (score 0):

Now I am after some changes on this code, but indeed it does not really work. I have a chess table that has 8 columns 8 rows. The official counting of the table starting from a1 - the left bottom corner to the h8 - the right upper corner. In the code I have the representation of this data in an array that actually starts from the left upper corner of the table and ends is the right bottom corner of the table. So it's a kind of tricky thing to get from the given alphanumerical data the one that is needed to address the array.
I ask you to please review the following method that converts the alphanumerical value to array address, because it occurs to me to jump into a bad phase (like sometimes 4 cells right, than other times just 2 cells right).

Thanks!

```
public void convertMoveToIntValues(KeyValuePair<string, string> move, ref Int16 fromNumInt, ref Int16 toNumInt)
{
    Int16 temp0, temp1;

    Byte[] fromNumTemp = { 0, 0 };
    Byte[] fromNum = {0,0,0,0};
    fromNumTemp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(move.Key);
    fromNumTemp[0] -= 97;
    fromNumTemp[1] -= 49;
    fromNum[0] = fromNumTemp[0];
    fromNum[2] = fromNumTemp[1];
    temp0 = (Int16)(56 - (Int16)(BitConverter.ToInt16(fromNum, 2) * 8 + BitConverter.ToInt16(fromNum, 0)));
    fromNumInt = (temp0 > 0) ? temp0: (Int16)(-1 * temp0); 

    Byte[] toNumTemp = {0,0};
    Byte[] toNum = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    toNumTemp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(move.Value);
    toNumTemp[0] -= 97;
    toNumTemp[1] -= 49;
    toNum[0] = toNumTemp[0];
    toNum[2] = toNumTemp[1];
    temp1 = (Int16)(56 - (Int16)(BitConverter.ToInt16(toNum, 2) * 8 + BitConverter.ToInt16(toNum, 0)));
    toNumInt = (temp1 > 0) ? temp1: (Int16)(-1 * temp1);
}
```